# Alter Update Statement SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

How would i alter this update statement so that if the value was not found in the `GENDERSPELLING` table the `GENDER` would be set to 'U'?

```
UPDATE DWCUST DW
SET GENDER = (SELECT NEW_VALUE FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
              WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE)
WHERE GENDER NOT IN ('M', 'F');
```

Comment: Do you mean `NEW_VALUE` field is `null` or no corresponding row exists in `GENDERSPELLING `?

Comment: select decode(new_value , null , 'U' , new_value) ...

Comment: no corresponding row exists @zarruq

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
UPDATE DWCUST DW
SET GENDER = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(NEW_VALUE) IS NULL 
           THEN 'U'
           ELSE MAX(NEW_VALUE)
           END
    FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
    WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE
)
WHERE GENDER NOT IN ('M', 'F');
```

Comment: @NedKhivju I have made a change can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` (or Oracle's `NVL`) to turn the `NULL` into a `'U'`:

```
update dwcust dw
set gender = 
  nvl((select new_value from genderspelling gs where dw.gender = gs.invalid_value), 'U')
where gender not in ('M', 'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question, i assume that you have two cases.

*`NEW_VALUE` column data is null*: Use `COALESCE`

```
UPDATE DWCUST DW
SET GENDER = (
        SELECT coalesce(NEW_VALUE, 'U')
        FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
        WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE
        )
WHERE GENDER NOT IN (
        'M'
        ,'F'
        );
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LMMR31749)**

*`CORRELATED sub-Query` returns no value:* Use extended `CASE`

```
UPDATE DWCUST DW
SET GENDER = CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT NEW_VALUE
                FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
                WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE
                ) IS NULL
            THEN 'U'
        ELSE (
                SELECT NEW_VALUE
                FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
                WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE
                )
        END
WHERE GENDER NOT IN (
        'M'
        ,'F'
        );
```

OR `COALESCE` outside:

```
UPDATE DWCUST DW
SET GENDER = coalesce((
            SELECT NEW_VALUE
            FROM GENDERSPELLING GS
            WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE
            ), 'U')
WHERE GENDER NOT IN (
        'M'
        ,'F'
        );
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JECYO69015)**